# La forma Mas Eficiente Para Crear Un DatePickerDialog

Tags: java, android-studio

Cual es la forma mas eficiente y con menos cantidad de codigo para crear un objeto tipo DatePickerDialog y que devuelva la fecha pero implementada para una función

```
String CrearDialogoFecha()
{
 //Aqui el objeto tipo DatePickerDialog
  DatePickerDialog dialogo;

 //Fecha Ingresada 
 String Fecha = "Fecha Ingresada";

  //Devolver la fecha
 Return Fecha;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Para llamarlo desde un método, primeramente tienes que crear la clase que generaría el dialogo.

```
import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
import java.util.Calendar;

public class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment {

    private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener listener;

    public static DatePickerFragment newInstance(DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener listener) {
        DatePickerFragment fragment = new DatePickerFragment();
        fragment.setListener(listener);
        return fragment;
    }

    public void setListener(DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        //Crea instancia de DatePickerDialog.
        return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), listener, year, month, day);
    }

}
```

En realidad el método mostraría el Dialogo y la única forma de obtener la fecha es cuando el usuario la selecciona, para esto crea una variable en donde se obtendrá la fecha cuando sea seleccionada en el dialogo:

```
  private String fechaSeleccionada;
```

este sería el método:

```
private void crearDialogoFecha(){
    DatePickerFragment newFragment = DatePickerFragment.newInstance(new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker datePicker, int year, int month, int day) {
            fechaSeleccionada = day + " / " + (month + 1 /* because moth starts with 0*/) + " / " + year;
            Log.i(TAG, "La fecha seleccionada es: " + fechaSeleccionada);
        }
    });

    newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: **CP 103 Cuando se califique con -1, es bueno para el sitio se indique la razón**, esto para mejorar la pregunta, eliminarla o si existen argumentos platicar sobre el tema.